# Element-wise multiplication of a matrix and a vector in DolphinDB

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication, dolphindb

Is there a built-in function in DolphinDB to element-wise multiply each column of a `m * n` matrix by a vector of size `m`?

To my knowledge, I can do this by using a `for` loop. Is there a more efficient way?

```
m = 1..1000000$1000:1000
n = 1..1000
for (i in 0:m.cols())
    m[i] *= n
```

Answer (score 1):

DolphinDB doesn't have a built-in function to do what you want exactly. But you can achieve this using higher order function `each`.

```
each(*, m, n)
```

Comment: I think the correct implementation is `each(mul{n}, m)`

Comment: According to the new edit of your question, you are right. The original code is m[i] *= n[i]